# error installing Subclipse 1.8.x on Eclipse Java EE Juno SR2 64bit

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, eclipse-juno

i tried to install it using Window -> Install New Software and then i gave the link http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

i tried restarting eclipse, restarting the computer. at first the installation goes without a hitch until it ran into this problem.

**Error from Eclipse: Problem occurred**

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.10.jar.
Connection reset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is there, try it from browser.  Must just be some kind of hiccup between Eclipse and the server or the network.

Note that Subclipse also provides zipped p2 repository you can download.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/archive/

Comment: what directory do i place the contents

Comment: The zipped download is still an update site.  So in the screen where you would add a URL, instead take the option to add a Local archive and browse to the zip file.  You then complete the install as if it were a URL